# Reactive function to read rtf in rshiny

Tags: shiny, reactive, rtf

I am new to R and RShiny.  Am building an application to compare two rtf files where a user can choose the two files dynamically.  Is there a reactive function that I can use to read an rtf file before I pass it on to renderDiffr? Here is one version of the code I generated but the issue I am having is for these two rtf files I pick under folder1 and folder2 should be passed to renderDiffr below.  I am sure there is a simple solution that I am yet to figure out. Would appreciate your help.

```
library(diffr)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Main title of the page
  titlePanel(HTML("<center>Comparison of two files</center>")),
  
  # Browse buttons to select files
  sidebarLayout(position="left",
                sidebarPanel(
                    #fileInput("selectfolder1","Select file from folder 1"),
                    #fileInput("selectfolder2","Select file from folder 2"),
                    # Submit button to perform the compare               
                    actionButton("goButton", "Compare", class = "btn-success")                   
                ),
  
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("folder1"),
    verbatimTextOutput("folder2"),
    diffrOutput("value")
  )))


shinyServer(
  
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    re1<-reactive({
        file1<-file.choose()
    })
    
    output$folder1<-renderText({
        re1()
    })
    
    re2<-reactive({
        file2<-file.choose()
    })
    
    output$folder2<-renderText({
      re2()
    })    
    
    re3<-reactive({
      input$goButton
        x<-diffr(folder1,folder2, before="Folder 1",after="Folder 2")
    })
    
    output$value<-renderDiffr({
      re3()
    })  
}
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What job would the reactive function need to do? In this form your question is rather vague. Maybe you can share some code so that others can see where the gap is that you need to bridge. It also motivates others to help you when they see that you already invested some effort. - If it's about uploading the file, you can do that with a `fileInput` widget ([a full example from the Shiny team is found here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/upload.html))

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have updated the question with my code.  Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/diffr/man/diffrOutput.html) you pass the result of `diffr()` to `diffrOutput()`.

What I changed:

- When you use a reactive function make sure that you return the result at the end of it. I use `return()` for clarity (though it's not necessary).
- In `diffr(folder1,folder2, ...)` I used `diffr(re1(), re2(), ...)` for obvious reasons.
- I also skipped the `re3` reactive In this sample and used `diffr()` directly in `renderDiffr`. But that is merely to reduce complexity.

```r
library(diffr)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Main title of the page
  titlePanel(HTML("<center>Comparison of two files</center>")),
  
  # Browse buttons to select files
  sidebarLayout(position="left",
                sidebarPanel(
                  #fileInput("selectfolder1","Select file from folder 1"),
                  #fileInput("selectfolder2","Select file from folder 2"),
                  # Submit button to perform the compare               
                  actionButton("goButton", "Compare", class = "btn-success")                   
                ),
                
                mainPanel(
                  verbatimTextOutput("folder1"),
                  verbatimTextOutput("folder2"),
                  diffrOutput("FileDiff", width="600px", height="auto")
                )))


shinyServer(
  
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    re1<-reactive({
      file1<-file.choose()
      file1
    })
    
    output$folder1<-renderText({
      re1()
    })
    
    re2<-reactive({
      file2<-file.choose()
      file2
    })
    
    output$folder2<-renderText({
      re2()
    })    

    # re3<-reactive({
    #   input$goButton
    #   x<-diffr(folder1,folder2, before="Folder 1",after="Folder 2")
    #   return(x)
    # })
    
    output$FileDiff <- renderDiffr({
      input$goButton
      diffr(re1(), re2(), before="Folder 1", after="Folder 2")
    })  
  }
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks Jan! This was helpful and helps solve my problem.  I am trying to enhance this to use read_rtf instead of file.choose so that the rtf control characters are not included in FileDiff.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: According to the way SO works, that would be a new question. If this answer helped solve your question, please accept it as answer, so that others know it works.